# Rounded corners on background-image CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a total noob so sorry about this question. I'm trying to get an image that I have set behind my h1 text to have rounded softer corners so it isn't just a harsh rectangle. I'm simply practicing the very few things I know about html and css by making a mock restaurant page, and I didn't learn how to do this but I've been banging my head into the wall trying to figure it out for a couple of hours now. I can get the image to round-corners with border-radius: 50px; but only when it's below the text. I'm writing my code in notepad++ if it matters and I'm not sure if it has something to do with the resolution or size of the picture. I also tried putting it in a div after seeing some suggestions on here but no luck with that. Here's my code and some screenshots:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
  <head>
    <title> Joe's Pizza Downtown GR </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> 
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1> Joe's Pizza </h1> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-family: Lobster;
  color: Orange;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url("cool-background.jpg");
}

.header {
  background-image: url("pizza-pepperoni.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

[Screenshot of rectangle behind text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQinv.jpg)

Thanks anyone that can help :)

EDIT:Fixed and final solution thanks!
[image: Fixed and final solution thanks!]

Comment: Your background isn't expanding to the width of the element. You should try altering the `background-size` property. You should be able to see it's working by using `background-size: cover` though not sure if that's actualy what you want to use http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peZXxo

Comment: Thank you! This worked :) I'm not really going for aesthetics currently, just trying to get it work.

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome. Lemme know if you'd like me to submit it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah definitely. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's because the background image isn't expanding to the far corners of the element it's assigned to, so the `border-radius` isn't clipping the image. You likely just need to modify the `background-size` property, or potentially use a different image. I'm using `background-size: cover` here, which will cause the image to stretch to fill the element without distorting the aspect ratio.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Lobster;
  color: Orange;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1> Joe's Pizza </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker Also fairly new to HTML here, but would you be able to reference the image directly in the HTML and then position it in the CSS with a z-index reference to put it behind the h1 text? `<img src="pizza-pepperoni.jpg alt="Pepperoni-Pizza">` for HTML, then `img { position: absolute; border-radius: 50px; margin-top: 200px; z-index: -1;}` for CSS.

Comment: @Jret yeah https://jsfiddle.net/yLdvg7dm/1/ or you can apply the border radius to the parent element and use overflow:hidden to hide the image overflow https://jsfiddle.net/yLdvg7dm/2/

Comment: @SirBilrach awesome, you're welcome. be sure to select it as the solution once you feel the issue is resolved.

Comment: I was having trouble with how wide the image was being, so if anyone has the same issue in the future trying to do something like this, I messed with the margins and changed the width to get exactly what I had envisioned from the beginning, here's just the div code I did:   ' ' `.header {
  background-image: url("pizza-pepperoni.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
 }`

Comment: I liked your answer

Comment: You should keep in mind, this is'nt a way how it works.... it's a workaround because you can't apply border-radius on the background-image it self, as the op asked. But you CAN apply it to a container and form the container. In this case the div. Just to clarify this :P